# Conditional Relate ID with email and name

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, relate

I'm trying to create a relation from some tables we could that the ID is the team they belong to, and the division is their role.(IN google sheets)(This table of information is in Sheet7)

[image]

Now I'm trying to create a conditional `IF B2(Value) is lower than 0.8`  give me the name and email from the person with the id and the division corresponding to that value. Here is my formula but it's not working `=vlookup(A2,if(B2=>0.8;Sheet7!A1:D16;""),2,0)` some help please! (This values tables is in Sheet8)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in F2:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B5>=0.8, IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 FILTER({Sheet7!C:C, Sheet7!A:D}, Sheet7!D:D=B1), {2, 3}, 0)), "xxx"))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 COLUMN(B1:E1)&"×"&B1:E1&A2:A&"×"&SUBSTITUTE(B2:E; "."; ",")*1); "×"); 
 "where Col2 matches '.*\d+$' and Col3 < 0.8"));; 2); 
 {Sheet7!D:D&Sheet7!C:C\ Sheet7!A:D}; {2\ 3}; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: And how about create a list with two columns for all the divisions?

Comment: @Eduardomaker also possible. can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: @Eduardomaker answer updated

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed